# Angular.js Interval is not updating with my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reasons the interval is not updating. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

```
function checkStates(){
    setInterval(function () {
            var app = document.getElementById('stx');
            scope = angular.element(app).scope();
                socket.emit('sendOpenInfo',user_id, function (data) {
                    if(data =='null') {
                        scope.clearStates();
                    }else{
                        scope.alterStates(data);
                    }
                });
    },10000);
}
```

Comment: There is a wrapper for interval in Angular JS. Try to use this one:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: As mentioned you should be using the built in `$interval` service. That's because unless you specifically kick off a `$digest` loop, Angular is not going to update the UI.

Comment: you need to inject $interval as a dependency, if you want to use only setInterval, you will need to call $scope.$apply manually to let angular know changes have been made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service:

```
function checkStates(){
    $interval(function () {
        var app = document.getElementById('stx');
        scope = angular.element(app).scope();
        socket.emit('sendOpenInfo',user_id, function (data) {
            if(data =='null') {
                scope.clearStates();
            }else{
                scope.alterStates(data);
            }
        });
    },10000);
}
```

Before using `$interval` you must inject it in your controller.